# Import excel chart with spin button to powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a chart in excel with a spin button that changes a value to change the chart when pressed.  I can import them into powerpoint by using insert -> object but this doesn't make the spin button usable.

I'm trying to get it so when showing the presentation I can click the spin button and the chart will correspondingly change, just like it does in excel.  Is this possible?

Comment: You might have more luck with this question on http://superuser.com.

Comment: @Stewbob this is probably a VBA-related question (or solution). The spin button is almost certainly attached to a macro, which may not persist when the chartobject is copied in to the PPT file.  OP will need to copy the macro's code and put it in a code module in the chart's datasheet workbook, and probably have to do some tweaking at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe spin button is connected to a macro and that's what's causing the chart to change in Excel.

You can copy the code from Excel and place it in a standard module in the Powerpoint file.

You will likely have to make some tweaks -- more or less, depending on how well the original macro was written (e.g., if it is full of `ActiveSheet.This` and `ActiveChart.That` then it's going to need a bit more tweaking than if it uses a `Chart` or `ChartObject` variable to represent the chart.

Here is an example of interacting with a powerpoint chart:

```
Sub TEST()
Dim sld As slide
Dim cht As Chart
Dim srs As Series

Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1) 'Modify to be the correct slide #'

'You can hardcode the shape by index if you know it, otherwise'
' this method will apply to the FIRST chart object found on the slide'
For i = 1 To sld.Shapes.count
    If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoChart Then
        Set cht = sld.Shapes(i).Chart
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'use a variable to interact with the Series:'
Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection(1) '<Modify as needed.'

'specify a particular formula for the series:'
'your macro likely changes the chart's source data/formula information'
' so something like this:'    
srs.Formula = "=SERIES(Sheet1!$B$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$5,1)"

'Or you can display the series formula:'
MsgBox srs.Formula

'Or you can toggle the series axis group:'
With srs
If Not .AxisGroup = xlSecondary Then
    .AxisGroup = xlSecondary
Else
    .AxisGroup = xlPrimary
End If


'etc.'
'Basically anything you can do to an Excel chart in VBA, you can do in PPT.'

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you copy/paste anything from Excel to PowerPoint, you get an OLE object.  What appears in PowerPoint is a Windows metafile *picture* of whatever you copied from Excel.  You'd have to either activate the Excel content (doubleclick it within PPT's normal view or give it the appropriate Action Setting to have it activate during a slideshow).  Then the spinner should also work within the instance of Excel that launches.

Or you could create another spinner in PPT and have it run code to modify the chart (using David's example code as a basis).